# Host different pages all together

Tags: dns, url, hosts, hosting, cname

Let's say I have got 5 websites in the different hostings each.

I want to create a page for each of them but host them all together under a subdomain of ONE hosting, For example.

www.site1.com -> At hosting A
www.site2.com -> At hosting B
www.site3.com -> At hosting C
www.site4.com -> At hosting D

www.site5.com -> At hosting E

Let's say I have got 5 websites in the different hostings each.

I want to create a page for each of them but host them all together under a subdomain of ONE hosting, For example.

www.site1.com -> At hosting A www.site2.com -> At hosting B www.site3.com -> At hosting C www.site4.com -> At hosting D

www.site5.com -> At hosting E

So :

Visiting www.site1.com should take you to what is in hosting A but if you visit www.site1.com/pageZ should take you to pages.site5.com/pageZ in hosting E(BUT YOU SHOULD STILL SEE THE SAME URL)

and the same for the rest... www.site2.com/pageY should take you to what is in pages.site5.com/pageY

how can I do that ?

Comment: If you need to clarify your original question, please edit the question.  Asking the same question twice will just cause one of your questions to be put on hold.

Answer (score 0):

Apache mod_rewrite is for you, the "Rewrite" methods combined with regular expressions should feat your needs perfectly

create a ".htaccess" file in your public dir at hosting A for example

insert this lines :

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On

    # redirect pageZ to http://pages.site5.com/pageZ
    # http://www.site1.com/pageZ redir to http://pages.site5.com/pageZ
    RewriteRule ^(pageZ)$  http://pages.site5.com/$1

    # redirect pageY to http://pages.site5.com/pageY
    RewriteRule ^(pageY)$  http://pages.site5.com/$1

    # calling any url starting with "page" and followed by any caracter
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(page.)$
    # then redirect the uri to the following
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://pages.site5.com/$1 [L]

</IfModule>
```

You can find a guide at : https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/misc/rewriteguide.html